Damerau-Levenshtein or HMM-based transducer for spelling correction?
I'm trying to build a spelling corrector that doesn't just give a list of options but ranks them probabilistically based on the kind of character substitutions, deletions, etc. that occur.
Basically I have an input and output string, and I want a probability score that one maps to the other via spelling errors.
One idea I had was to use Damerau-Levenshtein edit distance, but instead of using fixed costs per error, the cost would be variably chosen from a table of errors.  These costs would also be probabilistic, so rather than summation in the case statement of Damerau-Levenshtein, it would instead need to be a product (a joint probability of errors).
Another idea I had was to treat spelling errors as a hidden Markov model over a transducer, i.e. by defining types of error along edges in the hidden Markov model, and assigning probabilistic weights to these edges.  The probability of the given misspelling would then be the product of the edge weights leading to the consumption of both strings (correct string and error string).
Is this already being done elsewhere?  Maybe the two techniques are equivalent, but I first wanted to put the idea out there and see what others think.
One thing that has been mentioned to me is: why not use a transformer?  In my use case good execution speed is necessary.

probably not too helpful but an article about how people were doing this a while back: https://norvig.com/spell-correct.html

This is pretty cool.  I was about to use it, but then I saw that they take the basic a-priori probability of words as the ultimate probability of the spelling correction.  For example: ege would be corrected to 'the' instead of 'egg' using their approach.

I think that in the case of ege, egg would be preferred since it has a lower edit distance.

Okay, yes, this is true.  However, take another example: happynes.  In this case, 'happened' would be given as the correct spelling, when a more probabilistic approach would presumably return 'happiness'.

I've been working for a while on an innovative method for calculating distance, similarity and also string alignment, if it's useful to you:
https://github.com/pedrohcdo/PedroThermoDistance
If you can also share, I made this method available some time ago, the name I gave it is PedroThermoDistance&Similarity, it is a method primarily inspired by Levenshtain and Damerau-Levenshtain, but it goes further.
